# How to find directories where certain files exist but some others don't

Tags: bash, files, directory

Let's say I have lots of directories for reports and I always have a `report.md` file in directories with reports but `report.pdf` only in finished reports. I want to find directories where `report.md` exists but without `report.pdf`.

```
reports_dir
|
+-- project_xyz
|   +-- report.md
|   +-- image.png
|
+-- bugs
|   +-- report.md
|   +-- report.pdf
|   +-- Makefile
|
+-- homework
    +-- report.pdf
    +-- test.md
```

If I use this function as `search "reports_dir" --include "report.md" --exclude "report.pdf"`, it should return `/project_xyz` but not `/bugs` and `/homework`

What's the quickest way to do such a search in `sh`/`bash`? (one-liner preferred)

Comment: Any shell code can be put on one line. Bourne-like shells don't have a limit on the length of their lines of code, so it doesn't really make sense to ask for a *one-liner*. Putting shell code on one line just makes it less legible.

Answer (score 6):

```
for f in "$1"/*/"$2"; do dir=$(dirname -- "$f"); [ -f "$dir/$3" ] || printf '%s\n' "$dir"; done
```

Save the script as `search`. The first argument is the parent directory, the second is the include and the third the exclude.

```
sh search "reports_dir" "report.md" "report.pdf"
```

- `"$1"/*/"$2"` gets only the path of the files `report.md` in the example.
- `dir=$(dirname -- "$f")` gets the directory path of those files (assumes it doesn't end in newline characters).
- `[ -f "$dir/$3" ]` tests for the existence of the file in 3rd argument in that directory (`report.pdf`) and that's it's of *regular* type (not a directory, fifo, device...).
- `|| printf '%s\n' "$dir"` if it does not exist (or is not a *regular* file), print the directory name.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
print -rC1 -- **/report.md(DN^e['[[ -e $REPLY:r.pdf ]]']:h)
```

Would `print` `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn the `h`ead (dirname) of the `report.md` files under any level of subdirectories (`**/`) including `D`ot (hidden) ones, for which the `e`valuation of the `[[ -e $REPLY:r.pdf ]]` code does not (`^`) return true (where `$REPLY:r` is the `r`oot name of `$REPLY` containing the file to check).

With `find` implementations (such as GNU `find`) that allow `{}` embedded in `-exec` arguments and any Bourne-like shell (including `bash`), you can do:

```
find . -type d -exec test -e '{}/report.md' \; \
             ! -exec test -e '{}/report.pdf' \; -print
```

Though that means executing up to 2 `test` commands per directory.

With `bosh`  and its `find` builtin, that can be avoided with:

```
find . -type d -call '
  [ -e "$1/report.md" ] && [ ! -e "$1/report.pdf" ]' {} \; -print
```

Where this time, `-call` has the shell interpret that code directly and invokes the builtin `[`.

POSIXly:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
  for d do
    [ ! -e "$d/report.md" ] || [ -e "$d/report.pdf" ] || printf "%s\n" "$d"
  done' sh {} +
```

With those `sh` implementations where `[` and `printf` are builtin (most, these days), that should be relatively efficient as as few `sh` as possible are invoked by `find` to process the list of directories it finds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a short bash one-liner to test fore the existence of the PDF ( `-exec` is also a filter):

```
find . -name '*.md' -exec bash -c '[[ -f "${1%.*}.pdf" ]] && exit 1; exit 0;' bash-line {} \; -print
```

If you only want the directory name you can also put it in another `-exec` after the first one (`find` stops after the first test):

```
find . -name '*.md' -exec bash -c '[[ -f "${1%.*}.pdf" ]] && exit 1; exit 0;' bash-line {} \; -exec dirname {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, although the output could be a bit messy,
`ls -R | grep report.md | grep -v report.pdf`
The ls -R here lists directories reccursively, then greps report.md and grep -v means anything with report.pdf will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work?

```
comm -23 <(find -name "report.md" -printf '%h\n' | sort) <(find -name "report.pdf" -printf '%h\n' | sort)
```